# jquery-ui autocomplete position

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, position

I am using jquery-ui autocomplete to retrieve items from a SQL database which is working fine but I would like to move the autocomplete list to another part of the page.

I have been trying to use the Position option from [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-position) but cant seem to get the correct syntax when applying to my code?

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txtCity").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var param = { cityName: $('#txtCity').val() };
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test.aspx/GetCities",
                    data: JSON.stringify(param),
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item
                            }
                        }))

                    },

                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                minLength: 2//minLength as 2, it means when ever user enter 2 character in TextBox the AutoComplete method will fire and get its source data. 
            }


        });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Could you share your attempt at using the `position` option?

Comment: *"move the autocomplete list to another part of the page"* - is a very vague problem description. Please describe what exactly you want to do, what is not working and provide your failed attempt so that we can find what is the issue you're having with it, or a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to move the autocomplete box to the right hand side of the textbox.

After a nights sleep my first attempt again this morning worked fine, think I had originally only missed a comma in one of my attempts yesterday.

I just stripped it back to a basic implementation using an array instead of the ajax call and then applied the working syntax to my code.

Wasted FAR too much time on this yesterday, just shows taking a step back and time away from the screen helps work things out!

Thanks for your help

Working code for the record:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>JQuery AutoComplete TextBox Demo</title>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div><h1>AutoComplete Textbox</h1>
Software
<asp:TextBox TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#txtCity").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var param = { cityName: $('#txtCity').val() };
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.aspx/GetCities",
                data: JSON.stringify(param),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item
                        }
                    }))

                },

                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        position: {
            my: "left center",
            at: "right center",
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            minLength: 2//minLength as 2, it means when ever user enter 2 character in TextBox the AutoComplete method will fire and get its source data. 
        }
    });
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```